# On swipe down Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet skip HalfExpanded state

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I use Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout to show full screen BottomSheet. When user swipes this bottom sheet to the bottom in order to close it, it sticks at HalfExpanded state. And then user needs to swipe again to close it completely. How can I skip this HalfExpand and hide BottomSheet from first swipe.

Answer (score 3):

Compose 1.2-rc03 has a solution for the issue.

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHalfExpanded = true
)
```

You can use "skipHalfExpanded" property to full expand it.

Comment: `initialValue` is no longer an option in the latest Compose

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72890650/9636037), the new version of Jetpack Compose has a `skipHalfExpanded` attribute to support this requirement.

---

**Old Answer**

This swipes down to half state and animates to the hidden state.
This works, but the UI is a bit janky.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ModalBottomSheetSingleSwipe() {
    val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val modalBottomSheetState: ModalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    )

    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = modalBottomSheetState.currentValue,
    ) {
        if (modalBottomSheetState.targetValue == ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                modalBottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
            }
        }
    }
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            Text(
                text = "Bottom Sheet Content",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(all = 16.dp)
                    .background(LightGray)
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .height(200.dp),
            )
        },
    ) {
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        ) {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        modalBottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                    }
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Open Bottom Sheet")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
We have to use `modalBottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)` instead of `modalBottomSheetState.show()`

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem when you swipe a little ?

Comment: @AquaFreshka This works functionally. But the animation is janky.

Comment: when i swipe i little, it's get back to Expanded state, i have to swipe more than half screen in order to make the modal disappear. you said you had the same problem in you commentary ?

Comment: @AquaFreshka Check the updated image, I don't have to scroll more than half the screen for this solution to work. I have to swipe only a very small distance. (And that is required to detect this as swipe and not as touch)

Comment: I added your launched effect so i don't have to swipe more than half screen now, the problem is when i swipe, the modal stop in the middle to half expended then the launched effet happen and hide it, but i have like 1 second where it stuck on half screen.

Comment: @AquaFreshka Yes, exactly what I mentioned in the first line. Open to better solutions, but this was the closest I could find as of now.

Comment: What is the purpose of `key1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `confirmStateChange` parameter in `rememberModalBottomSheetState` function.

```
val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    confirmStateChange = {
        it != ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded
    }
)
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        ...
    }
) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Tried this, this has an issue, if you swipe very little, it will swipe down till your finger touches the screen, once you remove your touch, it snaps to Expanded state.