# Koltin Jetpack compose, ModalBottomSheetLayout stop in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, modal-dialog, android-jetpack-compose, fullscreen

I'am new to jetpack compose and i really liked it. But ran into a problem : I to have a modal that take all my screen size, following multiples tutorial i was able to do it using ModalBottomSheetLayout, Here is my code :

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun DetailsScreen() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)

    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .navigationBarsWithImePadding()
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .wrapContentHeight() //changed here to have full screen size, but it was only half screen, i had to slide with my finger to make the modal to full screen
                    //.height(200.dp) initial value i have a little modal on the bottom
                    //.fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.White)
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(10.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Bottom Sheet",
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Item 1",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Item 2",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Item 3",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        sheetState = sheetState,
        sheetBackgroundColor = Color.White
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = {
                        Text(
                            text = "Modal Bottom Sheet",
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        ) {
            MainContent(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        //sheetState.show() // changed here make the modal full screen at the beginning
                        sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainContent(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = onClick,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Click Me!",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6.copy(color = Color.White)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Problem i encounter : at first the modal was just at the bottom so i made my box to fillMaxSize to make it full screen, but it only open to half screen and i slide to swipe up to make it full screen.

Then i found that i could change sheetState.show() to sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded) to make my modal full screen from the moment it display. Perfect it's what i wanted. here is a screen of the modal :
[image: Modal full screen]

The problem is that now when i slide down to dismiss the modal it's stop half scree as bellow:

[image: Modal half screen]

From there i have to swipe down an other time to make it disappear. Also when it's on the middle i can swipe up to make it back to full screen. It's seem that there is 3 states: fullscreen, halfscreen, and gone. And the modal can be full screen or halfscreen. I would like to remove the half screen. So when i open the modal it's fullscreen and when i swipe down to remove it, it disappear without stoping in the middle. So i would have only one gesture to remove it.

Comment: Check if this solution works - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72547099/9636037

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get this behavior with skipHalfExpanded property:

`val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded, skipHalfExpanded = true)`

Comment: Thanks, @netjens - `skipHalfExpanded` was exactly what I needed. In my use case, on a partial pull down of the bottom sheet (which took up more than half of the height of the screen), would not hide the bottom sheet and leave some of it in view (and stuck in that mode until the bottom sheet was closed.)